# Current in an operational amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a question about some non idealities of operational amplifiers.

I know that no current flows into the operational amplifier due to two reasons:

1. Infinite input resistance
2. Infinite gain resulting in virtual short between the terminals in case of negative feedback.

What happens when one of these properties is not ideal?

Is it still OK to assume that no current goes to the operational amplifier?

Comment: A major difference between *op-amp* and *comparator* is the presence of negative feedback for the op-amp case. Using an *op-amp* as a comparator (no feedback) requires a careful analysis of input currents - overdriving inputs can cause significant changes to input current. OTOH, a *comparator* accommodates overdrive gracefully.

Comment: JustCurious - if this question has been answered then you should choose the most appropriate answer and formally accept it [using this method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png).

Answer (score 5):

> *I'm willing to ask what happens when one of these properties is not
> ideal . Is it still ok to assume that no current goes to the
> operational amplifier?*

Yes, this is OK to assume for most common op-amp circuits. As far as all common non-idealities, for general circuits, the most significant (IMHO) are at the top of this list: -

- Output voltage is only valid between the power rails and sometimes much less
- Input voltages are only valid between the power rails and sometimes much less
- Non-infinite open-loop gain (degrades the virtual ground and creates a small DC offset error)
- Non-infinite open-loop gain that decays at 20 dB/decade from about 10 Hz (degrades higher frequency AC performance)
- Input offset voltage error (produces DC offset voltage errors)
- Input bias current error (produces DC offset voltage errors)
- Input offset current error (produces DC offset voltage errors)
- Output voltage slew rate limitations (degrades higher frequency AC performance)
- Non-infinite input impedance (probably bottom of the list because so many op-amps are really good in this respect).

Of course, in non-general circuits or circuits that have specific requirements for more advanced op-amps, the priorities in the list above will change but, it's likely that most op-amps' input impedance is never a problem in 90%+ of applications.

> *What happens when one of these properties is not ideal?*

In all cases, the virtual ground assumption (not virtual short) is degraded and there will exist a few millivolt (typically) DC voltage difference between the two op-amp inputs. As frequency rises and other non-idealities come into play, there will exist a few millivolt to several hundred millivolt (typical) AC voltage difference between the two op-amp inputs.

Comment: This comment "(degrades higher frequency AC performance)" should apply to the previous item - "Non-infinite open-loop gain that decays at 20 dB/decade from about 10 Hz".

Comment: @KevinWhite oops - fix on its way

Answer (score 4):

Good question.

All real Op Amps are non-ideal.  There is always an input bias current, \$I_\text{in}\$ and an offset to the input bias current, \$I_\text{io}\$ before negative feedback for error correction is used, in addition to an input offset voltage \$V_\text{io}\$, so the result is output offset voltage, \$V_\text{oo}\$ that increases with forward gain.  You will find each of these variables in tables for all datasheets as well as some designs better for low bias current (FET inputs) and low offset voltage or both.

\$V_{\text{oo}} = A_v \times {V_{\text{io}} + I_{\text{in}} \times \Delta R_{\text{in}}+ \Delta I_{\text{io}} \times R_{\text{in}}}\$   = output offset voltage

\$\Delta R_\text{in}\$ is when you take the Thévenin equivalent resistance driving each input. Then when you take that difference times the input bias current, you get an additional input offset current.  Even when you have matched large input bias resistors and there is also  a tiny input offset current, \$\Delta I_\text{io}\$ this also adds to the effective input offset voltage, even if both Rin's are matched.

**This can be significant, even with pico or nanoamps times megaohms (source or reference) with high gain but **may be neglected AFTER you define your maximum acceptable output offset then choose the Op Amp and Resistor values** such that you can neglect \$I_\text{in}\$ and \$V_\text{io}\$.**  This is a normal design process.

You must always be sure each input is within the rated common mode \$V_\text{cm}\$ linear input range and the same for output otherwise the gain goes towards zero.

Comment: TY @Null for your edits.

Answer (score 1):

Op-amps are never ideal.

Current will flow in or out from op-amp input terminals as specified in the datasheets.

If the current is small enough to be irrelevant in your circuit, then you can assume the current is zero.

It just depends where you draw the line what amount is significant or irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

There is one (non-ideal) property of some opamps which is most important and not yet mentioned:

When the device is not "unity-gain compensated" (look at the data sheet) the opamp will - under certain circumstances - not work as an amplifier at all. Instead, it will most probably oscillate. The most critical case does exist for strong feedback, identical to a small closed-loop gain.

However, there is a method called "external frequency compensation" which can heal the opamp in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases there is influence on the output. This has to be taken into account in critical designs.

- finite input resistance: some of the current in the input network is siphoned off as input bias.

The effect depends on the design and signal state: it can reduce gain, add offset, or both. High gain and/or high impedance designs will suffer more degradation.

Input bias current can be mitigated by making both input networks be the same impedance so that input bias current has equal influence on the inputs, thus reducing offset error. Keeping the impedance lower also helps.

It will still reduce gain, so this can be compensated by adjusting the feedback.

- finite gain: the gain is less than predicted, and the inputs will have an offset equal to Vout/Av, where Av is the open-loop gain.

The larger the system gain, the more this error will have influence. Keeping the gain lower helps. Op-amps designed for high gain applications will have higher open-loop gain than common op-amps.

This error can be mitigated by adjusting the gain to compensate.

**Further Reading**

[https://secs.oakland.edu/~ganesan/old/courses/SYS595%20F06/non%20ideal%20opamp%20equation%20TI.pdf](https://secs.oakland.edu/%7Eganesan/old/courses/SYS595%20F06/non%20ideal%20opamp%20equation%20TI.pdf)

[https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee105/fa14/lectures/Lecture04-Non-ideal%20Op%20Amps%20(Feedback%20circuit).pdf](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eee105/fa14/lectures/Lecture04-Non-ideal%20Op%20Amps%20(Feedback%20circuit).pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Both the input current and the gain are specified in data sheets.

For the input current, there are three components here:

1. A DC current, often (perhaps mistakenly) called bias current. Depending on the opamp's design, it might be anything from picoamps to a microamp. This current will create a voltage drop over the signal source impedance and create a DC error, just like the offset voltage.
2. The opamp input has a finite input impedance (both to the power supply, and to the other input). If you apply a voltage, a proportional current will flow. The effects of this one are arguably a bit trickier to analyze, and it depend on the actual circuit. Typically the impedance is on the order of 10-100 kOhms for BJT opmaps, and giga ohms for FET opamps. At AC frequencies, the input impedance is capicitive, maybe 10 - 100 pF.
3. Current noise, which is like the bias current, but spans all frequencies, not just DC.

Figuring out which one of these effects are of importance for your design (and, consequently, how you can mitigate them) is exactly your job as the designer.